# White Screen xCode Simulator Ipad 12.9 inch 2nd and 3rd gen

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ipad

I've developed my app using Ionic and it works on my Iphone 6s but not on the simulator, I've read that it was because the device version, so when I tried Iphone 8 plus it worked like a charm. But when I try to get the screenshots of Ipad 2nd and 3rd gen to send to Apple Store, it's not working. It displays my splash screen but doesn't show any content after that. Just an white screen. And there's nothing being logged on xcode output.

I've already tried using another versions of xCode and it's still not working

Comment: What's your minimum iOS version set for the project?

Comment: Needs more information about the project setup and iOS versions, SDK versions, etc.

Comment: I've tried to set the latest iOS version and then the 10.0 to 12.2 (Ipad). I've tried xCode latest version, 12.4 and 13.1

Comment: I think that is your problem. I didn't release an app from Ionic ever, but as I know, iPad 2nd gen can run up to iOS 9.3.5, but you set the project to be 10 and up. Make sure your simulator meets the minimum requirements of the project.

Comment: Also, verify that you have specified the "Initial view controller" in your storyboard.

Comment: It is setted to be the initial view controller

Comment: I'm gonna try lower versions of iOS, thanks

Comment: Or better use newer versions of devices? I guess if you go too low, like iOS 8 or 9, it might be not so nice to maintain the code for those low versions.

Comment: Apple Store requires ipad 2nd and ipad 3rd gen screenshots so I can upload my app update. Is there a way I don't need to send those screenshots?

Comment: AppStore requires iPad Pro 2nd and 3rd gens. That is different than regular 2nd and 3rd generations, and these devices can run on latest iOS versions. In the end, you need to upload pictures of exact sizes what AppStore is expecting. Here is a good guideline of the sizes that you need: [link](https://appradar.com/de/blog/ios-app-screenshot-sizes-and-guidelines-for-the-apple-app-store)

Comment: I've got the idea. On the simulator devices it shows that runs on IOS 12.2, but it's not working as expected. There's someway I can get those pictures without running my app on a simulated device?